# Detect output to tty

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tty, pty

I'm making a program to automatically type out the password when trying to ssh. The idea is I'll run my type_pass executable in the background and then start the ssh process. Something like

```
$ type_pass & ssh user@host.com
```

Currently this works as I've given a small delay (5 seconds) in the type_pass application it self.

type_pass looks something like

```
void typeout(int tofd, char* txt, int usecs = 100000) {
  int len = strlen(txt);
  for(int ii = 0; ii < len; ++ii) {
    usleep(usecs);
    int ioctlerr = ioctl(tofd, TIOCSTI, &txt[ii]);
    int err = errno;
  }
}

int main() {
  sleep(10);
  typeout(1, "asdas\n");
}
```

My question is how can I intelligently wait for the password prompt from the server and then start sending out the keys for the password?

Comment: May be, try `expect` instead?

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using a private/public key? Or use the `sshpass` command.

Comment: The server is installed over and over.. But the password remains same. And I don't have access to preserve the authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expect script that I use for this purpose:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

send_user "password: "
set old_timeout $timeout
set timeout -1 
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
set timeout $old_timeout
set password "$expect_out(1,string)\r"

spawn /bin/bash

interact {

-o -nobuffer "assword: "  {
        send $password
}

}
```

The above program asks the end user for the password and then stores it in the password variable.  In this way, the password is never written to a file but expect will  echo the output to the terminal.  There is code that can be added to turn the echo off but I don't know it offhand.

Expect then launches a bash interactive shell.

From this point on, expect reviews all the output to the terminal.  If a string is output that contains "assword:", expect will output the stored password variable.

By the way, I am not a fan of expect, but I find this program to be helpful in many cases including ssh.

I've also found sshpass to be helpful for your particular problem.  I've also used ansible for similar work - but you have enough here to solve your problem.